# How to write a commom class for two ViewModel classes?

Tags: wpf, c#-4.0, wpf-controls, binding

I have two viewmodel classes called `ChangePwdViewModel.cs` and `ExpiringPwdViewModel.cs`.
`ChangPwd.xaml` binds to `ChangePwdViewModel` and `ExpiringPwd.xaml` binds to `ExpiringPwdViewModel`.

Both have the property as below.

```
private string _message;
public string Message
{
    get { return _message; }
    set { _message = value; OnPropertyChanged("Message"); }
}
```

In each class, there's a function called `ValidatePwd()` to validate the new password.

In this function, Message property is updated.
Eg.

```
if (IsAlphaNumeric(this.NewPassword) == false || IsAlphaNumeric(this.CfmPassword) == false)
{
    this.Message = "Invalid new password, only characters and numbers are accepted, password must contain at least one character and one number";
    this.ResetPasswordFields();
    return false;
}
```

I want to create a common class to write this function and used by two viewmodel. But, How can I update the Message Property  of the viewmodels from this class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about putting it in a base class:

```
class ViewModelBase
{
    private string _message;
    public string Message 
    {
        get { return _message; }
        set { _message = value; OnPropertyChanged("Message"); }
    }

    public bool VerifyPassword(string newPassword)
    {
        ....
    }
}

class ChangePwdViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
}

class ExpiringPwdViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
}
```

**Update**:

If you can't use a base class because your view models already have a base class then you could use an interface as suggested by others. However this means that you will still have to implement the interface in all your view model classes so you don't gain that much in terms of avoiding multiple implementations (except that you have a contract for your view models then which is usually a good thing to have).

You can achieve some kind of "multiple inheritance" in C# by using a tool like [Dynamic Proxy](http://www.castleproject.org/dynamicproxy/index.html) which allows you to create mixins. So you could implement the `Message` property and password verification in one class and then create a mixin proxy which merges the view model with that implementation. It's not as nice as you will have to create all your view model instances via the proxy generator but it can be made to work. Have a look at this [tutorial](http://kozmic.pl/2009/08/12/castle-dynamic-proxy-tutorial-part-xiii-mix-in-this-mix) if it sounds like an option for you.

Comment: @David this is a very neat way of doing it, not a workaround.

Comment: I used sth like this, 
ChangePwdViewModel:SubAppView,MessageInterface
And then, change the fucntion  ValidatePwd() to ValidatePwd(MessageInterface msgInterface)
{
  //Process Validation Logic.
  msgInterface.Message="xxxxxxxxxxx";
}
Thanks for you answer.

Answer (score 1):

You could have the two ViewModel classes implement a common interface, say IMessage that implemented a single property - Message.

Then your common class or a function would take a parameter of type IMessage that it could use to update the message.

Comment: Hi, Can you explain a bit more ? I still don't get it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to avoid base classes (could cause potential design issues in future) in such cases, I would rather suggest to pass through constructor an algorithm of validation, smth like this:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public MyViewModel(Func<bool> validationAlgorithm)
    {
        // ... save function to use later for a validation
    }
}
```